# How can I make execute a button press for an addon on startup?

Tags: modeling

Im trying to change some settings in the MeasureIt addon in blender.
I want the button to Show the segments on startup, but I cant seem to configure the init file to do this. The problem now is that each time I start blender I have to press "Show" for the segments to display, I want this to happen on startup as default.  Pressing it and saving startup file doesnt work either.
[image]

Comment: 1: In my opinion, modifying the configuration of an addon is not really an issue with using the tools in Blender and I would consider it off-topic on this site. Others might think different. 2: What does this have to do with `modeling` since this is the tag you're using for this question?